# Having trouble pushing a specific key into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I just learned how to create a function for a for loop.
Here's what we have:

```
function each(array, func) {
    for (var i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
        func(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to take an already made function that's using a for loop, and replace it with each.

```
   var people = [
  {name: {first: "Alyssa", middle: "P.", last: "Hacker"}, age: 26},
  {name: {first: "Ben", last: "Bitdiddle"}, age: 34}
];

function ages1(people) {
  var acc = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    acc.push(people[i].age);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

This function returns [26, 34]

So now I created this:

```
function ages(people) {
    var acc = [];
    each(people, function(age) {
        acc.push(people[i].age);
    });
    return acc;
}
```

I'm getting an "i is not defined" error. How else can I push each age into the new array if I can't use i to reference each number?

Comment: func(array[i]); <-- you already have array element, all you need is to change acc.push(people[i].age) with acc.push(age.age).

Comment: now learn how to step into and debug the variables using your browser dev tools ...writing code is only 1/2 the battle...learning to debug it yourself is  most valuable

Comment: Why not just `var ages = people.map( x => x.age);` -> https://jsfiddle.net/2jyv9w0o/

Comment: When you remove the es6 lambda function that isn't widely adopted its very similar - syntactically - to a `foreach`, but would take longer.

Comment: Iterated 10,000 times - results: `foreach: 17.753ms | map: 77.583ms`

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
function ages(people) {
    var acc = [];
    each(people, function(person) {
        acc.push(person.age);
    });
    return acc;
}
```

By the way, javascript has a native `forEach` function that does what your `each` function does, and is probably faster / more robust.

It's in `Array`'s prototype so it's used on the array like this:

```
people.forEach(function(person) {
    acc.push(person.age);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I see how it works if I use function(age) then acc.push(age.age) or any other word like function(glabargh) and acc.push(glabargh.age) but why do we do this?

Comment: Because in your `each` function, it feeds in the current person to your function (called a callback), you then Define it in the top `... function(person){ ...` so now person, inside the function, equals the current array item.